# New Document from Content Type different options based on folders

Tags: content-type, document

is it possible to remove content types from the new options in ribbon, based on folder names or field information or do I need to implement my own logic? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like that this topic is not really interesting. :( I will try to find a usable solution and will report about if there is an interest on it.